# MS SQL 2005 Express on a Phenom 9650

Tags: sql-server-2005

Will MS SQL 2005 Express run and utilize the quad core processor of a Phenom X4 9650?

Answer (score 4):

It will install and run, however Express will only utilize one processor at a time.  There is no parallel processing with Express.  Windows will see multiple cores as multiple processors so the quad core will be seen as 4 processors.

See the [**Engine Specifications**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345154%28SQL.90%29.aspx#sseover_topic4) section of the SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Overview at MSDN.

Comment: Hmpf. Why 2005?

Comment: @Tom: what do you mean "Why 2005?"

Comment: Current version: 2008 R2, released some days ago. 2008 was reolease 2008. 2005 is an OLD version.

Comment: @Tom: price isn't the only determining factor...

Comment: Given2005 combpatibility modes - pretty much it is.

Comment: @TomTom - [1] There's more to compatibility than just the fact that an app has legacy compatibility modes, it has to be tested, [2] The question clearly asked about SQL Express 2005, [3] Chill out.

Answer (score 0):

It will work. It will utilize ONE PROCESSOR - which you have (cores do not count, they get utilized). iIt will NOT parallelize, but if you get multiple queries at the same time (web applicaiton, for example, many pages being served at the same time), they will execute in parallel.

At least in 2008 R2 - may I ask why you insist on using a 2005 SERIOUSLY OUTDATED database server? It is not the upgrade costs ;)